# line number not works for fancyvrb with SaveVerbatim

Tags: fancyvrb

The following code tells every thing

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{SaveVerbatim}{FOO}
    However,
    if I define an reusable Verbatim by SaveVerbatim,
    line number failed to works.
\end{SaveVerbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left]
    This works.
    Because I use Verbatim directly.
\end{Verbatim}

\UseVerbatim[numbers=left]{FOO}
\BUseVerbatim[numbers=left]{FOO}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a bug, which won't be fixed.

Comment: Why won't? Is there any discussion about it? I found an email report this bug 10 year ago, but no related reply found yet.

Comment: Feel free to provide a patch and it will be fixed ...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a patch that works for me:

```
$ cat fancyvrb.sty.patch 
992c992,993
<   \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
---
>   \def\FV@FirstNumber{#1}%
>   \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
1128,1129c1129,1139
<         \FV@TheVerbatim\FV@ProcessLine{##1}}}%
<     \gdef\FV@TheVerbatim{}%
---
>         \FV@TheVerbatim\advance\c@FancyVerbLine\@ne\FV@ProcessLine{##1}}}%
>     \gdef\FV@TheVerbatim{%
>       \edef\@tempa{\FV@FirstNumber}%
>       \def\@tempb{auto}%
>       \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
>         \c@FancyVerbLine\FV@CodeLineNo%
>       \else%
>         \c@FancyVerbLine\FV@FirstNumber%
>         \advance\c@FancyVerbLine\m@ne%
>       \fi%
>     }%
```

[image: result with the patch applied]

If you apply it locally, for example, by copy/pasting the following into a unix shell prompt:

```
cat > fancyvrb.sty.patch
992c992,993
<   \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
---
>   \def\FV@FirstNumber{#1}%
>   \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
1128,1129c1129,1139
<         \FV@TheVerbatim\FV@ProcessLine{##1}}}%
<     \gdef\FV@TheVerbatim{}%
---
>         \FV@TheVerbatim\advance\c@FancyVerbLine\@ne\FV@ProcessLine{##1}}}%
>     \gdef\FV@TheVerbatim{%
>       \edef\@tempa{\FV@FirstNumber}%
>       \def\@tempb{auto}%
>       \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
>         \c@FancyVerbLine\FV@CodeLineNo%
>       \else%
>         \c@FancyVerbLine\FV@FirstNumber%
>         \advance\c@FancyVerbLine\m@ne%
>       \fi%
>     }%
  C-c C-c
patch -o fancyvrb.sty $(kpsewhich fancyvrb.sty) fancyvrb.sty.patch
```

I've also emailed this to the package maintainer (Herbert Voß), maybe they could tell me how to proceed towards a proper patch/fix.

Comment: The BVerbatim numbering doesn't work even with regular verbatim (non-saved), so I didn't patch it.

Comment: Will be fixed in `fancyvrb`. Thanks for the patch!